# Unpacking a lists of list, into individual lists using another list

Tags: python

**Problem:**
I have a List of lists (`lists_of_lists`), that each contain 5 floats in each list. I am trying to unpack `lists_of_lists` and for every unpacked list, name it using the values in my `country_list`

**Example of desired output:**

Brazil = [28.42, 56.12, 59.97, 61.69, 60.34]
British = [39.1, 57.96, 56.29, 56.5, 71.25]
Note: the ordering in both lists correspond, as demonstrated above.

**Resources:**

`list_of_lists = [[28.42, 56.12, 59.97, 61.69, 60.34], [39.1, 57.96, 56.29, 56.5, 71.25], [14.3, 42.33, 58.54, 41.24, 49.76]]`

`country_list = ['brazil', 'british', 'cantopop', 'mandopop', 'french', 'german', 'indian', 'iranian', 'malay', 'philippines-opm', 'spanish', 'swedish', 'turkish']`

**My thinking:**
is that I should use a for loop to iterate through the `country_list` and for every string (country name), create a new list and populate using the same positioned list in the `list_of_lists`

Any hints would be great. Thank you

Comment: Try this.
>>> dict(zip(country_list,list_of_lists))
{'brazil': [28.42, 56.12, 59.97, 61.69, 60.34], 'british': [39.1, 57.96, 56.29, 56.5, 71.25], 'cantopop': [14.3, 42.33, 58.54, 41.24, 49.76]

This will create a dictionary with key value as country name and the corresponding list as value.

Answer (score 3):

```py
dict(zip(country_list, list_of_lists))
```

will give you a dictionary of country: list, as

```py
{'brazil': [28.42, 56.12, 59.97, 61.69, 60.34], 'british': [39.1, 57.96, 56.29, 56.5, 71.25], 'cantopop': [14.3, 42.33, 58.54, 41.24, 49.76]}
```

As you can see the shortest element zipped is used (here country_list).

Answer (score 0):

`enumerate` gives you iterator for both index and value

```
list_of_lists= [[28.42, 56.12, 59.97, 61.69, 60.34], [39.1, 57.96, 56.29, 56.5, 71.25], [14.3, 42.33, 58.54, 41.24, 49.76]]

country_list = ['brazil', 'british', 'cantopop']

# to print
for idx, country in enumerate(country_list):
    print(country, list_of_lists[idx])

# to store in a dictionary:
d = dict((country, list_of_lists[idx]) for idx, country in enumerate(country_list))
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating "named" variables makes no sense. Put them into a dictionary:

```
list_of_lists= [[28.42, 56.12, 59.97, 61.69, 60.34], 
                [39.1, 57.96, 56.29, 56.5, 71.25], 
                [14.3, 42.33, 58.54, 41.24, 49.76]]

country_list = ['brazil', 'british', 'cantopop', 'mandopop', 'french',
                'german', 'indian', 'iranian', 'malay', 'philippines-opm',
                'spanish', 'swedish', 'turkish']

merger = {k:v for k,v in zip( country_list, list_of_lists)}

print(merger)
```

Output:

```
{'brazil': [28.42, 56.12, 59.97, 61.69, 60.34], 
 'british': [39.1, 57.96, 56.29, 56.5, 71.25], 
 'cantopop': [14.3, 42.33, 58.54, 41.24, 49.76]}
```

Shortest list wins. You can use the dictionary, to get all of brazils values:

```
print(merger["brazil"])    # [28.42, 56.12, 59.97, 61.69, 60.34]
```

To get all values iterate the dict:

```
for key in merger:
    print(key)
    print(merger[key])
```

Output:

```
brazil
[28.42, 56.12, 59.97, 61.69, 60.34]
british
[39.1, 57.96, 56.29, 56.5, 71.25]
cantopop
[14.3, 42.33, 58.54, 41.24, 49.76]
```

See:

- https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Answer (score 0):

I would create a dict to store the results.

```
myDict = {}
for i in range(len(list_of_lists)):
    myDict[country_list(i)] = list_of_lists(i)
```

Comment: I suppose this answer is irrelevant; it does the same as what @kuco 23 mentioned.